# Check if a string (char *) can be enumerated

Tags: c, char, decimal

I'm trying to find a way to check if a read-in char * can be represented as a number (with or without decimal places) or not.  Essentially I am asking, if I have a text file containing the following:

```
-1.9e-3
e9
1e9
1ee9
-1-.9e3
.9e3
.9.e3
```

It would be able to recognize that line 1, line 3, and line 6 can be "enumerated" into valid numbers, whereas all of the other lines contain erroneous inputs.  I know this could be done with brute force, but there is potentially an unlimited number of possibilities that could be wrong.  It would be much easier if there was a function that read in the entire char * and can just say,  "Yes that string of characters can be represented as an actual number" or "No that string of characters cannot be turned into the number that it intends to be."

And by enumerated I mean that the string `(char *)` can be the number that it wishes to represent.

Comment: [man `strtold()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strtold)

Answer (score 1):

Just use [`strtold()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strtod), it will tell you if it succeeds, and also give you the converted number.

Comment: @FelixPalmen Sure, why not. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just try to convert it with [`strtold()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strtold) and use the possibilities to check for errors, e.g.

```
char *x = "-1.9e-3";
errno = 0;
char *endptr;
long double xnum = strtold(x, &endptr);
if (*endptr) // (&& *endptr != '\n' if you read with `fgets()`)
{
    // extra / invalid characters;
}
else if (errno == ERANGE)
{
    // out of range;
}
```

Comment: so the if(*endptr) statement... What else would go in there?  I don't fully understand the // extra / invalid characters; comment

Comment: @sdepot see the linked manpage. after `strtold()`, `*endptr` points to the first character that couldn't be converted. You expect this to be `0` (the end of the string) on a successful conversion (or maybe a newline, `\n`, if you read from a file with `fgets()`).

Comment: Ok so I am using fgets to read in each line in its entirety, but I am reading in each "number" (there is more than one "number" on the line typically) on the line using strtok(), would that change anything?